# Couchdb documents fields data converted into �

Tags: java, couchdb, character-replacement

I am working on web application with java using database couchdb. I am facing a strange error on my database. The Data entries in couchdb are getting converted into a speacial character(�). Multiple lines of this character gets inserted in database field due to which te particular document is unable to be viewed/open as well functionality breaks at point.I have searched a lot and read a lot about this character but still unable to find the reason for this replacement of  Strings.[image]

Comment: maybe an encoding error, but impossible to tell without code

Comment: What exactly code you want as I am getting this problem at various place just on inserting in couchdb

Comment: create the shortest possible code example that produces the problem

Comment: This problem can occur  at any part of my code. I still don't know from where exactly I am getting  this error.

Comment: @priya CouchDB is using JSON over HTTP to insert/update data. JSON is always UTF8, so check your given data for correct utf8-conversion.

Comment: how to check for correct  utf-8 conversion in java code

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of flash and changes done by google in chrome please enable the flash on your browser and than check the entries.

to enable flash go to https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/enable-system-flash-player-google-chrome.html link

Hope your error will resolved ASAP.